# What are the drawbacks of a liquid hydrogen jet engine?

Tags: jet-engine, fuel, engine-design

I am looking into building a jet aircraft utilizing liquid hydrogen as a fuel source. I have already built a few original design pulse jets, and I'm looking for a new project.  Cryogenic fuel jet engines look good, but I feel there may be drawbacks.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-powered_aircraft

Comment: Welcome! The title and the body of your question follow different directions: Title: LH2 used for cooling, body LH2 used for combustion. Could you clarify?

Comment: @mins I edited the title. I believe the OP mean that the fuel is cryogenically cooled and not the engine

Comment: The biggest drawback is keeping the fuel in a liquid state. This requires a very complex cryogenic cooling and storage system. Also, if the aircraft crashes, expect a really big fireball with no survivors.

Comment: 1: Cryogenic fuel
2: Reactivity with alloys aircraft construction
3. Engine damage and high temperatures

Comment: Related (LH2 is used for space exploration since many years): [Explosive lessons in hydrogen safety - NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/513855main_ASK_41s_explosive.pdf) // and // [Assessment of crash fire hazard of LH2 fueled aircraft](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19830002825.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few drawbacks:

1. Lesser energy density per volume

For the same amount of energy, you need more space, not yet available in current designs

2. Boil off

The hydrogen will slowly boil off, and vented to the atmosphere. Hydrogen IS dangerous, and this will negatively impact long flights.

3. Logistics

Fuel is common everywhere in the world and easy to store. We have yet to build a world delivery network for hydrogen.

Comment: @reirab on It is not.  I edited the bullet point to clarify, but if you read the sub text you'll see that I was clearly speaking about density per mass and not per kg. So yes the fuel will weight less but take a huge amount of space.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, missed that part. When I see "energy density" I normally think per mass. The volumetric energy density of LH2 is only around a quarter of that of jet fuel.